# android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

When I'm clicking a button, that is indeed inside an LinearLayout, I get this error on this line:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
```

My method looks like this:

```
 public void adjDoa(final View view) {

    final CharSequence[] items = {"Get on with it!", "Doable!", "Maybe, maybe not.",      "Unlikely!", "When pigs fly!"};

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetItActivity.this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose doability!");
    dialogBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
            TextView text = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.tViewChDoa);
            text.setText(items[which]);
        }

    });
    dialogBuilder.create().show();
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: You have Button and your casting Button to LinearLayout.

Comment: So what calls the adjDoa method?

Comment: I think that it means that when the onClick is called, `view` is a Button, not a LinearLayout, and you cannot cast a Button to LinearLayout

Comment: Try this 
       `LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) view.getParent()`

Comment: The method is called when clicking the button in the linearlayout. It brings up a alertdialog from which you choose one of the five alternatives. But when I click OK after selecting one alternative it crashes. Not sure what to do, it worked when I had scrollview. So what should I use instead of view? Yes, I'm new to this... :)

Comment: Although I also answered, I downvoted because you don't show your layout XML so it is really hard for us to answer your question -- we simply have to guess. And if you would have examined your XML more, maybe you would have figured out the problem yourself.

Comment: Well that's the problem when you're new at this. You don't know what to look for exactly and it's therefore also hard to know what code to show here. Sometimes it feels like you have to be an expert to be able to post a question correctly, which counteracts the function of stackoverflow a little bit...

Comment: @andysando To post a question correctly, the most important think to do is to clearly show what your question is and what you have tried, and give details about your situation to help people answering your question. You seem to be on the right track though since I get the feeling that you want to learn how to use SO better.

Comment: Yes of course I want to learn SO, becuase I find it to be a huge resource for information. But you mentioned a part of the problem. If you are new, like me, and have no actual clue what the problem is you cant show what you have tried because you haven't tried anything. It's a little catch-22 here before you are skilled enough. But thanks for helping me out here...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it can be as easy as [sockeqwe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18876079/1310566). Sometimes this error can happen if you have copied/pasted/moved a part of your layout XML to another part of the XML. If that is the case, cleaning the project through Project -> Clean will resolve that problem.

---

In this particular case it seems like you want the parent of the button, in which case you need to call `view.getParent();` like this: (Here I am typecasting to ViewGroup instead of LinearLayout because it really doesn't matter which kind of layout the parent is)

```
ViewGroup ll = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
```

If you only have one view with the id `tViewChDoa`, you don't need to get the `LinearLayout` before you get that view, if you have this code in your activity then this will work:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewChDoa);
```

Comment: Part of this answer was correct. I removed the `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;` Originally I didn't use that line, but I also didn't have the "final" in `public void adjDoa(final View view)`. So to sum it up, it was the addition of "final" that did it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I didnt understand your comment above, but what you saying makes absolutely no sence. And you should also avoid to use getParent(), beacuse it breaks a little bit the concept of decoupling view (XML) and functionality (java code). If one day you change your xml layout for this component (insert another parent Layout, or i.e. switch from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout) getParent() will throw a CastException. So at least use View as type instead of LinearLayout: View ll = view.getParent(); However the best solution would be to already pass the correct view as parameter in adjDoa()

Comment: @sockeqwe The way I see it is that the view parameter is a button (since this is an onClick method from what I understand). And he wants to get the TextView which is in the same layout. I modified my answer to cast to ViewGroup instead of LinearLayout because you have a good point there. I did also include in my answer that in reality, if there is only one view with the id *tViewChDoa* you can call `findViewById` on the activity and you will get the correct view.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Allright :D But He could also use View instead of ViewGroup, if the only thing he wants to do is to call findViewById()

Comment: @sockeqwe @SimonAndréForsberg.
Thank you for continuing to discuss this, it is really interesting. But as I wrote above it now works, and the only thing I did was to remove `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;` and change `TextView text = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.tViewChDoa);` to `TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tViewChDoa);`
@sockeqwe Are you saying that shouldn't work?

Comment: It works, because you use now the Activity.findViewById(). Just a tip: I would recommend you to to call findViewById(R.id.tViewChDoa) in your Activity.onCreate(). findViewById() is a expensive operation because it has to traverse (in worst case) all child views in the main layout (hence ListView should use ViewHolder). So if you call `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tViewChDoa);` as reaction on a ClickEvent could lead to a bad user experience because pressing / releasing the button could look a little bit laggy. It should not be a big deal in 95 % of your activities, but I just want to mention it

Answer (score 2):

The View you have passed as parameter in adjDoa(final View view) is a Button and not a LinearLayout!

Therefore it cant be cast to LinearLayout and raises this exception.

Check which parameter you pass to this method